# html 5 website giving different result in chrome and firefox

Tags: jquery, css, html, google-chrome

here is link of website i m developing

it is html 5 based template site developed using core php
site looks fine under fire fox,IE but in chrome there is vertical line comes at the center of slider area, i am not able to find whats causing problem

i have tried to solved with help of firebug but was not able to track down issue

can anyone help me with this ?

here is css code for slider container

```
#slideshow-container {
background: url("../images/slideshow/bg_slideshow.jpg") no-repeat scroll center center #999999;
float: left;
margin-bottom: 39px;
overflow: hidden;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Seems the vertical line was produced by **//*[@id="slideshow-content"]/div/div[2]/div/span**

who has a style : **'content: "\e0fb";'**

I delete this and the vertical line disapeared.

---

There is my new perfect solution:

Your customed icon svgs is not compatible with webkit? ( safari fails to display icons too) But the **woff** file works fine!

In your **base.css**:

```
url('../fonts/Batch-master.svg#Batch-master') format('svg'),
url('../fonts/Batch-master.woff') format('woff'),
```

swap these two lines, and chrome will read **woff** and use it.

```
url('../fonts/Batch-master.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/Batch-master.svg#Batch-master') format('svg'),
```

Comment: And the icon doesn't show up as well. I think "\e0fb" represent an icon in unicode, which is correctly shown in IE but not in chrome. Perhaps these two browsers is not using the same font library. Or decodes unicode differently

Comment: @user1600124 Maybe you could use an icon image to present an icon.

http://www.utf8icons.com/character/57595/UTF-8-character

Comment: Well.. yeah.. I mean.. just deleting this line doesn't help fix the problem, you should replace it with an icon image. So a complete answer should be a replacement, not just deletion.

Comment: thanks for help first,

yes vertical line removed when deleting  'content: "\e0fb";' but it also removes  image at center of circle how can we show image ?

Comment: Please help i am really stuck into this

Comment: finally i found solution, property content also support url feature
i create images for that 3 icons and replace
content: "\e0fb" with content: url("../images/icon.png")

it works find under all browsers

Answer (score 0):

I used chrome Inspector and found that the problem is with the font you have for your site. Namely, `'Batch-master'` If you change the font size to 0px or removed the Batch-master font-family, then the line goes away.

Change your `.circle-icon` class to `font-size: 0`

This should remove the line.

Comment: and all the icons go away

Comment: I tried overwriting the `.circle-icon` class with inspector and the lines did go away. While keeping the circles intact.

Comment: Please help i am really stuck into this

Comment: Did you try to edit the css file like I suggested in my answer?